# Create PostgreSQL external table with multiple character delimiter

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have many text files containing data like in below example, which I need to load into my PostgreSQL DB thru external tables.

NAME1#@!AGE1#@!EMAIL1#@!ADDR1#@!CELL1

NAME2#@!AGE2#@!EMAIL2#@!ADDR2#@!CELL2

where #@! is delimiter . I cant use single ASCII character delimiter as I have 100s of such (big) tables n files and nearly all single character delimiter occurs as part of my data.
is there any way I can use multi character delimiter in postgressql external tables? or any other solutions ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this directly with `file_fdw`. You'll have to preprocess the file.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe for your quick reply . This is running DWH and we are using "~" as delimiter and its creating issues as it is part of data. so I want to use multi character delimiter.
what kind of preprocessing you are suggesting

Comment: Choose a single character as delimiter that is not part of the data. It can be an exotic or non-printable character like `E'\u0008'` or `E'\U0001D11E'`.

Comment: @Sam Just check this - https://rextester.com/OVHG94158 . If you can manage to import the DWH data into PostgreSQL, you may use something like this

Comment: Thanks @VivekS. for your response and efforts. This option is not feasible for me as there are 100s of tables and they are very big in size so changing whole structure (adding intermediate table)  is not possible and it will also impact the performance of daily operations.